# Gradle Jar structure is different than the real project structure

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build

I'm trying to build my project with gradle but for some reason the resources are put on a different level than their real level. 
Here's the build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
version = '1.1'
archivesBaseName = 'DesktopOmegle'
repositories {
//mavenCentral()
maven {
    url 'http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/' 
    url "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2"
}
}
dependencies {
compile 'org.json:json:20090211'
compile 'org.fxmisc.richtext:richtextfx:0.6.4'
}
jar {
    from { 
         configurations.compile.collect { 
         it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) 
         } 
    }

    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'main.java.client.OmegleClient'
    }
}
task copyDeps(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into 'lib'
    rename { 
           String fileName ->
           fileName.replace('-20090211', '')
    }
}
build.dependsOn(copyDeps)
```

and here's the actual structure of the project (displaying only src folder):

```
|src-
|   main-
|        java- 
|             client-...
|             server-...
|        resources-
|                  images-...
```

The resulting jar structure is as follows:

```
|jar-
|   images-...
|   main- 
|        java-        
|             client-...
|             server-...
|   META_INF-...
|   org-...
```

Obviously that's not what I want. I want the images in the jar to be inside main.resources as they're in reality. Why isn't the jar adhering to the real structure of the project? Can someone help me correct this situation?

EDIT:
Code snippet for accessing the resources:

```
ClientConstants.RESOURCES = "/main/resources/images/";
if (status.equals(ClientConstants.STATUS_OFFLINE)) 
{
    img = ClientConstants.RESOURCES+"ON.png";
    action = "Connect";
}
else 
{
    img = ClientConstants.RESOURCES+"OFF.png";
    action = "Disconnect";
}
Image imageConnect = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(img));
ImageView viewBottom = new ImageView(imageConnect);
```

Comment: This structure is correct. What is the real problem?

Comment: The images folder isn't where I want it to be. I want the jar structure to be identical to the project's structure. Meaning the images shall be in main.resources. Is that possible?

Comment: Probably it is, but it doesn't comply with the standards.

Comment: Seems a bit weird. In the code I find the images in their intended path of main.resources.images, but when I run the jar because of this structure the images aren't found (the code is still searching them under main.resources.images). Seems logical that the jar adhere to the original structure of the project.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Jar file has a structure that was established by a long time ago - and is a de facto and *de iure* standard. Project structure introduced by maven and used by gradle is a quite a new concept - introduced for humans for better recognition. Both maven and gradle makes an out jar in the same, compatible with standards way.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Thanks for that interesting overview. So how should I go about handling this? How is this situation usually handled, where the jar puts resources in one place but at runtime searches them in a different place. Right now my project is generating useless jars.

Comment: How do you read the files in the code? Could you please provide a runnable example?

Comment: The project is quite big so it's difficult for me to give a runnable example. It's available on github under the name DesktopOmegle. But in general, I edited the question with the code I use to access the resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your project is managed by gradle you should always use standard layout introduced by maven or have a good excuse to using any different layout. [Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/30861126) you can find sample project that shows how to use the this layout and read the resources that will be later included in jar. Such resources will be always put under root of the jar file. And below you can find sample code that illustrates how to read such files:

```
private void readResource(String path) {
        InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader)) {

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("LINE: " + line);
            }

            scanner.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Sample code taken from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/).